# Does auto return type deduction force multiple functions to have the same return type?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, return-type-deduction

Consider the below snippet:

```
struct A
{
  auto foo(), bar();
};

auto A::foo() { return 1; }
auto A::bar() { return 'a'; }

int main()
{

}
```

It compiles fine in Clang++ 3.7.0.

It [fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaed22cd1a6c550f) in G++ 5.2.0:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'auto A::bar()':
main.cpp:7:24: error: inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'int' and then 'char'
auto A::bar() { return 'a'; }
```

Does auto return type deduction force multiple functions, declared in a single statement, to have the same return type?

Comment: MSVS 2015 will also compile without warning/error.

Comment: just curious: does anybody ever file those compiler bugs which are found here on SO?

Comment: In your case (https://goo.gl/i09xpE) Clang implicitly casts 'a' to 97.

Comment: That is the kind of code I would hate to see in a codebase.

Comment: @m.s. I don't follow C/C++ tags much but I've seen like tens of cases where bug reports were reported (and a lot of times a fix was provided pretty quickly too).

Comment: Frankly I don't even know C++ supports such a syntax for function declaration.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Based on the following, GCC has the right behaviour in this case, but only by coincidence (see below):

> §7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]/8
>
> > If the init-declarator-list contains more than one init-declarator, they shall all form declarations of variables.

Why only by coincidence? The error message is a clue. Changing the functions to deduce the same return type causes GCC to compile the code. While it's correct in giving an error here, albeit a misleading one, it only does so when the deduced type is inconsistent. It should always give an error.

Comment: So did we learn that the snippet is malformed and both clang and gcc are "correct"? Or is clang wrong in accepting the code?

Comment: Does this quote imply that the statement `auto foo(), bar();` is malformed because it tries to declare functions not variables?

Comment: chris, your answer sounds as if GCC was right to reject the code on the basis of using multiple function declarations in a single statement. this is allowed, I'm more interested whether `auto` leads to ambiguity

Comment: @Ruslan, That is my interpretation of it. If someone knows better than I do, then I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: @MarcAndreson, Yes, that is an accurate description of my answer. I would like a stronger basis than my quotation for why it is permissible to declare multiple functions this way if you're going to argue that it is indeed permissible ("this is allowed").

Comment: @chris so, the question is, does §7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]/8 apply only when an `auto` placeholder is used?

Comment: @MarcAndreson, Yes, the section is about the `auto` specifier specifically.

Comment: @chris I think you should reword your answer, i.e. put emphasis that this is not a valid declaration and, actually, all compilers are wrong

Comment: @MarcAndreson, Done :)

Answer (score 25):

Yes.

`auto` doesn't mean "any type", it means a specific type that the compiler is supposed to deduce.

This is not specific to function declarations, `auto i = 1, f = 4.7;` doesn't work either.

Also, declaring multiple functions in a single statement doesn't seem like a good idea anyway.

Comment: Can you provide a standard reference? I know that in case of variables, any ambiguity in type deduction fails, but this is slightly different and I wish I had clarity, since the two compilers have different view on this subject